# how i set angulrajs checkbox ng-model to multiple select in laravel foreach and pass values to angularjs controller

Tags: php, html, angularjs, laravel-4

I need sample code please..

i tried to set ng-model like

```
data-ng-model="barcodeData.items.<?php echo $items->item_code; ?>"
```

and also tried

```
data-ng-model="barcodeData.items.{{$item->item_code}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cannot pass number or special characters as a object i just pass like

`data-ng-model="barcodeData.items[<?php echo $items->item_code ;?>]`

like this now its work

Answer (score 0):

ng-modal use like this :

```
ng-model="barcodeData.items.{{$item->item_code}}"
```

Comment: i did it..but not work..  `  item_code ` is a integer value.. is that the problem